# How to highlight data ranges in excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, automation

I wonder is there a way to replicate insert chart dialog functionality using C#. What I need is to display a Popup window, but more importantly to let the user to select data ranges.

I also want ranges highlighted with Excel's colorfull boxes. Here's an image of how excel highlights ranges when inserting a chart. I'd like to be able to have these boxes from my C# add-in.

[Excel range highlighting http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/5290/excel.png](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/5290/excel.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA there is a RefEdit control that can allow you to do this, and there is a detailed walkthrough on how to use it here: [How to Use the RefEdit Control with a UserForm](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/213776).

There is no built-in control that can allow you to do this in C#, unfortunately. You could either use VBA as your front-end -- which I very much doubt that you'd want to do -- or you can create a RefEdit control equivalent using C#. There is an article on how to do this, along with a fully-functional C# code example, here: [How to Code a RefEdit control](http://blogs.msdn.com/gabhan_berry/archive/2008/06/12/net-refedit-control.aspx) by Gabhan Berry.

**Update based on zzandy's comment:**

> "Actually the question is on how to
>   highlight selected ranges, not on how
>   to select range. The InputBox
>   (csharp-examples.net/inputbox) is
>   available from C# and allows to select
>   ranges."

Getting the ranges to highlight in multi-colors will not be possible. That kind of highlighting only occurs in Excel when creating formulas on the worksheet, not when one is selecting ranges for any other purpose. The only way to create that would require an heroic amount of subclassing, or hooking, and I would not recommend it.

Some solutions, however, will allow you to at least have a marquee band around the selection (aka "marching ants"). If you use VBA as a front end, you could make use of the built-in [RefEdit control](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/213776), that I mentioned above, which does put the marquee band around the selected range.

[The C# example I gave, above](http://blogs.msdn.com/gabhan_berry/archive/2008/06/12/net-refedit-control.aspx) would allow you to use a RefEdit-like control within a C# form, but it would not include the marquee band when making selections -- it will simply utilize the standard look when a range is normally selected.

If you are willing to use a simple input box solution, instead of a control on a form, then that [C# example you gave](http://www.csharp-examples.net/inputbox/) would work (if you use Form.Show() but *not* Form.ShowDialog()), but it would not show any special marquee band or other highlighting. For a simple input box that *does* use marquee band selection, you could make use of the [Excel.Application.InputBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.inputbox(office.11).aspx) method, passing in a value of '8' for the 'Type', which indicates that the value returned by the 'InputBox' method should be an 'Excel.Range' data type:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = ...;

string prompt = "Please select the range.";
string title = "Input Range";
int returnDataType = 8;
String DefaultRange = oXL.Selection.Address();

Excel.Range myRange = excelApp.InputBox(
                          prompt,
                          title,
                          DefaultRange,
                          Type.Missing,
                          Type.Missing,
                          Type.Missing,
                          Type.Missing,
                          returnDataType)
```

Hope this helps...

Mike

Comment: Thank you, looks like it's as close as one can get to where I want.

Comment: Yes, this is the best you will be able to do with C#. The only other way is to use VBA as a front-end so that you can use a VBA UserForm along with a true 'RefEdit' control.

Comment: Actually the question is on how to highlight selected ranges, not on how to select range. The InputBox (http://www.csharp-examples.net/inputbox/) is available from C# and allows to select ranges.

Comment: Multi-colored highlighting like that is pretty much impossible, unless you are constructing worksheet formulas on the worksheet. I updated my answer above to address this. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I may be a bit outdated here, but have you tried to record a macro that does what you want?

You could then look at the generated code and adapt it as needed.

Comment: It doesn't help. The ranges are not being selected explicitly.

Comment: the issue is with the ability to replicate some of the refedit controls functionality, not with a specific part of the Excel object model.